# Passing different URL parameters to AJAX function in Django

Tags: javascript, html, django, ajax

How to pass the different URL names to the javascript function. Here are my HTML and Javascript code.

```
{% for profile, g_name in group_list %}
    <li class="contact">
        <div class="wrap">
            <img src="{{profile}}" alt="No image" />
            <div class="meta">
                <input type="hidden" id="myGroup" name="myGroup" value="{{g_name}}">
                <button onclick="GetMessages()">
                    <p class="name">{{g_name}}</p>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
{% endfor %}

<script>
    function GetMessages() {
      var myGroup = document.getElementById('myGroup').value;
      $('.ajaxProgress').show();
      $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "/getmsgs/"+myGroup,
          success: function(response){
              $("#display").empty();
                ...
          },
          error: function(response){
              alert("No Data Found");
          }
      });
  }
</script>
```

and this is my URL

```
path('getmsgs/<str:word>/', views.groupmsgs_ajax, name='groupmsgs_ajax'),
```

when I try the above method I am getting the first 'myGroup' id value. it is passing the first group name by default.
I am not able to call other group names.

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because all input elements have the same id `myGroup` so `document.getElementById('myGroup').value` get always the first element value.

The following code changes should solve the issue given that `g_id` exists and is a string

```
{% for profile, g_name, g_id in group_list %}
    <li class="contact">
        <div class="wrap">
            <img src="{{profile}}" alt="No image" />
            <div class="meta">
                <input type="hidden" id="{{g_id}}" name="{{g_id}}" value="{{g_name}}">
                <button onclick="GetMessages({{g_id}})">
                    <p class="name">{{g_name}}</p>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
{% endfor %}

<script>
    function GetMessages(id) {
      var myGroup = document.getElementById(id).value;
      $('.ajaxProgress').show();
      $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "/getmsgs/"+myGroup,
          success: function(response){
              $("#display").empty();
                ...
          },
          error: function(response){
              alert("No Data Found");
          }
      });
  }
</script>
```

Or pass the name directly to `GetMessages` function

```
{% for profile, g_name, g_id in group_list %}
    <li class="contact">
        <div class="wrap">
            <img src="{{profile}}" alt="No image" />
            <div class="meta">
                <button onclick="GetMessages({{g_name}})">
                    <p class="name">{{g_name}}</p>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
{% endfor %}

<script>
    function GetMessages(myGroup) {
      $('.ajaxProgress').show();
      $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "/getmsgs/"+myGroup,
          success: function(response){
              $("#display").empty();
                ...
          },
          error: function(response){
              alert("No Data Found");
          }
      });
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Nice it worked for me I added getElementById like
<button onclick="GetMessages(document.getElementById('{{g_id}}'))">
Shukran